# How to create filter in mantis to see only recently added issues like last 2 weeks

Tags: mantis

I would like to create a filter which when selected displays cases/issues that was opened/resolved etc in last 1 week or 2 weeks instead of hardcoded times. I have found these kind of queries to be extremely useful in other bug trackers. I can set fixed time stamps to report issues in that interval but it is not particularly that useful. It's best to save a filter which is generic. Does anyone know if this can be done in MantisBT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*: the reference bug for this feature is [0009398: Filter Enhancements](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=9398)

---

I don't think this is possible in the current MantisBT code base ( I'm one of the developers ). Either raise a feature request at [the MantisBT bugtracker](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/) or look for a plugin which does that.